# whitespace at start of XML doc is causing error

Tags: php, xml

I'm generating an XML response when an error occurs in my script, however the XML response contains the error "XML declaration allowed only at the start of the document". From the research I've done, I gather this is caused by whitespace before the opening XML declaration. (which is exactly what my XML response has.)

```
 <?xml version="1.0" charset="utf-8"?>
<conv>
    <error code="1000">Required parameter is missing</error>
</conv>
```

I cannot however find the source of this problem? Here's the code that generates the response:

```
function result($data,$errnum,$type='XML') {
    switch(strtolower($type)) {     
        case 'xml':

            // Build the XML body
            header('Content-Type: text/xml');               
            $xmlpage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" charset=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
            $xmlpage .= "<conv>\n";
            $xmlpage .= "\t<error code=\"$errnum\">$data</error>\n";
            $xmlpage .= '</conv>';

            echo $xmlpage;              
        break;
    }
    exit;
}
```

Any ideas?

EDIT-

I ran the page through a whitespace removal tool and it has removed the whitespace at the start BUT I'm now getting a new error:

```
<?php
function error($errnum=1000) {
$data = array(
'1000' => 'Required parameter is missing',
'1100' => 'Parameter not recognized',
'2000' => 'Currency type not recognized',
'2100' => 'Currency amount must be to 2 decimal places',
'2200' => 'Currencies cannot be the same',
'3000' => 'Service currently unavailable',
'3100' => 'Error in service'
);
result($data[$errnum], $errnum);
}
function result($data,$errnum,$type='XML') {
switch(strtolower($type)) {
case 'xml':
// Build the XML body
header('Content-Type: text/xml');
$xmlpage = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" charset=\"utf-8\"?>\n";
$xmlpage .= "<conv>\n";
$xmlpage .= "\t<error code=\"$errnum\">$data</error>\n";
$xmlpage .= '</conv>';
echo $xmlpage;
break;
}
exit;
}
?>
```

**Error:** error on line 1 at column 19: parsing XML declaration: '?>' expected

Edit 2: Removing charset=\"utf-8\ fixes it! But I need that there so I'm confused as to why that's causing the problem?

Comment: Is there any whitespace in your script?  Before the `<?php`?

Comment: No whitespaces / line breaks in the `.php` file before the opening `<?php` tag?

Comment: There may be whitespace before/after any <?php or ?> tags in any files use by your script. You can omit any ?> tag at the end of your PHP files

Comment: Check to make sure that there is no whitespace before <?php OR after any closing ?> before this script.

Comment: I updated OP with some new developments

Comment: A couple ideas:  1) Put text before your XML.  See if the junk is coming from the XML string, or somewhere else.  Next, echo out a character at a couple spots in your script to track down where the stray output is coming from.  2) Do you really need an XML declaration?  It's not strictly required by most parsers. 3) Building XML in strings is sketchy.  Though this is NOT your specific problem at the moment, it will be when you accidentally include a <&' in your XML. Try using DOM methods to build XML wherever possible.

Comment: Ok - I've found that by removing charset=\"utf-8\" it fixes it! Why is this causing the problem though :S

Comment: ok, I believe it's because "charset" isn't actually valid XML. It should have been "encoding"!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this!

I used this tool to remove whitespaces:
http://www.design215.com/toolbox/whitespace.php

I also had "charset" set in my XML declaration where it should have been "encoding". EG:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<conv>
    <error code="1000">Required parameter is missing</error>
</conv>
```

Answer (score 0):

Check file encoding; make sure if you are using UTF-8, it's without BOM.

Comment: changed encoding to UTF8 but it didn't help I'm afraid.

Comment: tried that but no luck still :(. Check my OP as I've managed to remove the whitespace but I have a new error now.